# Laravel get contents of Excel to insert in Database

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I'm having a problem while uploading excel file and update data to my database using Laravel 5.6 and Laravel Excel(maatwebsite 3.1) i can't get the contents of each column to update the data in my database.

`$rows` return empty

```
Model:

namespace App;

use App\User;
use App\MyModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class DataImport implements ToCollection
{
    /**
    * @param array $rows
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        dd($rows);
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $import = MyModel::where('user_id',$row[1])->first();
            $import->field1= $row[2];
            $import->field2= $row[5];
            $import->field3= $row[3];
            $import->status = 'SUCCESS';
            $import->save();
        }

    }
}


Controller:

    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;

    public function postImport(Request $request){
        if($request->hasFile('sample_file')){
            Excel::import(new DataImport ,request()->file('sample_file'));

            return redirect('/import');
        }

    }
```

Excel File:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| #  | USER ID | FIELD ONE | FIELD TWO | FIELD THREE | FIELD FOUR | FIELD FIVE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |    1    |   123-abc |  abc-123  |    123123   |    asdf    |   konjesh  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($request->hasFile('sample_file')){
   $getPath = Request::file('sample_file');
   $data = Excel::load($getPath, function($reader){ })->get();
   if(!empty($data){
      Excel::import(new DataImport , $data);

      return redirect('/import');
   }
}
```

Can you try this,

Comment: i think that's for the previous version of Maatwebsite 2.1

Comment: O sorry mate, forgot to see the version of yours. Yeah I think that is 2.1, It was coded on my old poject way back 2017. My bad.

Comment: it's ok mate no problem