# How to bulk import user data which also has a profiles table in laravel using Maat maatwebsite/excel package?

Tags: excel, laravel, import, maatwebsite-excel

I have a Model User it has one to one relation with model Profile.

The profile table has two columns user_id integer column and 'information' jsonb column. I have a csv file that has a list of users with their name id , information and many more. What I want is to store the informations from the csv file to my users table and profiles table.

I am able to store information in users table. But unable to store users profile information in profiles table json column.

Here is how I am passing data from controller to excel

```
 public  function  import(Request $request)
    {
        Excel::import(new UsersImport,request()->file('file'));

        return back();
    }
```

Here is the UsersImport Class Code

```
class UsersImport implements ToModel
{

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User ([
            'student_id' => $row[0],
            'name' => $row[1],
            'email' => $row[2],
            'password' => '123456'


        ]);

    }

}
```

User Table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('student_id')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

profiles table:

```
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->jsonb('information')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54433860/laravel-get-contents-of-excel-to-insert-in-database/54433946#54433946

Answer (score 1):

//Replace new User with User::Create

```
class UsersImport implements ToModel
{

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'student_id' => $row[0],
            'name' => $row[1],
            'email' => $row[2],
            'password' => '123456'


        ]);

      $user_id = $user->id;
      return $user;    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It may work

```
class UsersImport implements ToModel
{

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $user = new User ([
            'student_id' => $row[0],
            'name' => $row[1],
            'email' => $row[2],
            'password' => '123456'
        ]);

        //create a profile for user, I'm assuming that you have model Profile for profiles table
        Profile::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            //and other profile data    
        ]);  
        return $user;

    }

}
```